# Basically I'm trying to get the one row that says the movie title and the min(cost) which would be the min from the cost column

Tags: min, oracle9i

```
What are the names for the least expensive movies in the collection?  Show both the title of the film and the cost.
```

table name is movies
and the column name im trying to get a min() from is "COST"

i've tried everything i know to solve it, 
select title, min(COST)
from movies.

basically im trying to get the one row that says the movie title and the min(cost) which would be the min from the cost column, any help would help me a lot.

im using sql i9

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT TITLE, MIN(COST) FROM movies GROUP BY TITLE LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: error 
SELECT *, MIN(COST) FROM movies GROUP BY COST
        *

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: what other columns does your table have?

Comment: MID,  TITLE,  GENRE,  YR,  LENG,  FORMAT,  COST,  PURCH_DATE,

Comment: try 

SELECT TITLE, MIN(COST) FROM movies GROUP BY TITLE;

Comment: this is as close as I got, the result is most of the movies in the table 99 out of 110 movies are displayed. really confusing

Comment: ok do SELECT TITLE, MIN(COST) FROM movies GROUP BY TITLE LIMIT 1;

Comment: error 

 GROUP BY TITLE LIMIT 1
                *

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended